# Mathematical Symbols in Figure

Tags: floats

How can I add mathematical symbols in figure or draw figure and put mathematical symbols on it?

Comment: We need soooo much more information if we are to help you.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I reckon [Drawing on an image with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559) should pretty much do the job :)

Comment: what kind of figure? You can replace text with `psfrag`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Sorry that we can't really help without more information. The best way to provide that is by way of a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. If you are drawing on an existing image see the link that @Werner linked to. If you are doing the figure in LaTeX you add math text the same way you add math to normal text in that you with a pair of `$` (or a `\(` and `\)`) .  If you provide a MWE you can get a more detailed answer.